# Selecting all the string values that match, from XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2012

I need to retrieve all sentences that end with a '+' from an XML column. The current query that I have, only retrieves the first sentence.

Here are the XML contents:

```
<file>
  <row>Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. +</row>
  <row />
  <row>Special duty officer(s) required for event. There are charges for these services.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>8’ pedestrian pathway must be maintained on sidewalks throughout event area.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Provide and maintain access to the Hotel during event.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area.|</row>
  <row />  
</file>
```

You can see that there are three rows with sentences that end with a '+'. I run this query:

```
SELECT b.value('(./row/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [row]
FROM @xmlstr.nodes('/file') AS a(b)
WHERE right(b.value('(./row/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1) = '+'
```

But I only get the first sentence, and I need all of the sentences with the plus sign in the end.

If someone could help me to figure this out, I would be very thankful

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT b.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [row]
 FROM  @xmlstr.nodes('file/*') AS a(b)
WHERE  b.value('.','nvarchar(max)') like '%+'
```

**Returns**

```
row
Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. +
Special duty officer(s) required for event. There are charges for these services.+
Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+
```

Answer (score 2):

John's solution is great, just to offer an alternative, you might call `XQuery` to check for the last character like here:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<file>
  <row>Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. +</row>
  <row />
  <row>Special duty officer(s) required for event. There are charges for these services.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+</row>
  <row />
  <row>8’ pedestrian pathway must be maintained on sidewalks throughout event area.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Provide and maintain access to the Hotel during event.~</row>
  <row />
  <row>Event organizer/sponsor is responsible for cleanup of event area.|</row>
  <row />  
</file>';

SELECT r.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(1000)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/file/row[substring(text()[1],string-length(text()[1]),1)="+"]') A(r);
```

The result

```
Addendum and/or contract providing additional event details and conditions. +
Special duty officer(s) required for event. There are charges for these services.+
Notify Mall Crew of electrical needs for activities.+
```

Comment: Wow!  The xquery approach has 15% of the execution plan batch vs my 85%.   Once again I learned something new.  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Really that much? Did not expect this... Yours might be improved with `text()[1]` instead of `.` and `/file/row` instead of `file/*`. Furthermore, I'd expect a `RIGHT(REVERSE(),1)` to be faster then `LIKE '%+'`... Or a `SUBSTRING` to get the last character as above in the XQuery... However, thx for the upvote :-)

Comment: No change with /file/row   but I did gain FOUR whole percentage points with right(...,1)   :)